# Capistrano error on bundling compass from git

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano, bundler, compass-geolocation

When I try to deploy to my newly set up server, capistrano throws this at me.

```
*** [err :: fupifarvandet.dk] fatal: Could not parse object '22e2458b77519e8eb8463170c1a1fe4bab105f3e'.
 ** [out :: fupifarvandet.dk] Git error: command `git reset --hard 22e2458b77519e8eb8463170c1a1fe4bab105f3e` in directory /var/www/apps/fupifarvandet.dk/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/compass-22e2458b7751 has failed.
 ** [out :: fupifarvandet.dk] If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/var/www/apps/fupifarvandet.dk/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/compass-dcbe0c41f22c777e90babfa80d61f78dfdea41b2'
```

This is from my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'compass', git: 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git', branch: 'rails31'
```

What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is no `rails3.1` branch on github. Try `gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.alpha'`